# I have 1000 rows php session file, which has to be displayed one by one to user, I would like to avoid data transport

Tags: php, session

I have 1000 rows php session file, which has to be displayed one by one to user, I would like to avoid or reduce data rotation. Which is best way?

Comment: poor information provided , please edit your question with an example.

Comment: Can get get a sample of the data?  Also, a little more information about the use case might be helpful.  How/why is the user reading this data one line at a time?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Are you saying that you have a 1000 rows of data in a php session? If so why? Don't you have access to a MySQL database?

Comment: session array file contains list of product details for various product, it has to be show one by one or according to user's selected product.

Comment: So this is a shopping cart. You are going to have provide more information or someone will vote this down. Also I can't think for the life of me why anyone in their right mind would store product descriptions in a session array.

Comment: yes. To reduce MySql work load, I am using session, I feel this is one better for my site, Is any way to store session file on client system?

Comment: a session is really not the way to cache your data. Use memcache for that kind of things, so you can reuse your cache over multiple users and not clog your application with huge session files. And a client site session file is a cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you only keep user-specific information in the session data.  For example, the items that the user has put into his shopping cart could go there.

If you want to reduce the load on your db server when retrieving the catalog, then you want to do some kind of caching.  There are a lot of choices, but the most common ones are:

- memcached.  This runs as another process on your web server (or perhaps on a nearby server).
- APC.  This my personal favorite for simple deployments.  It is an add-on to PHP, but once it is installed you don't have to manage or watch any additional server processes.
- File system.  This is easy to implement, and doesn't require any new software or add-ons or processes.  All you need is a directory that can be written to by the web server.

The basic idea is this: the function that fetches your catalog data would:

```
Retrieve the catalog from the cache.
If the catalog is not in cache
    Get the data from the database
    Create the catalog object/array
    Save the catalog to the cache
Return the catalog
```

With memcached and APC, the data is automatically serialized for you, and you can declare how long you want the data to be cached.  The data will disappear from the cache once its time has run out.  That way, you can make sure you refresh your catalog from the database at reasonable intervals.

If you are using the file system, you have to do a little more work for yourself.  You have to check the age of your cache file (to see if it is time to refresh the data), and you have to call `serialize()` and `unserialize()` to turn your data object into a savable stream of bytes and back again.

When you render your HTML pages, you only have to put the information into them that the user will see.  There's usually no need to send the entire catalog to the user all at once.

If the catalog is quite large, then you might consider caching individual items in the catalog in separate cache entries, instead of putting the whole thing into cache.  You really have to be the judge of how large is "too large".  Typically, network I/O is the big latency problem for web servers and databases so you can read a surprising amount of data from disk without showing any performance degradation (over a hundred kilobytes before you ever notice anything).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a session variable to store product data and to avoid data. If you want to reduce weight you can use css in your html files and you can use shorter function and variable names. In generally product data is stored in a (mysql) database. There is also sqlite that works with normal files when you want to avoid special databases.  You can also compress your product data and uncompress in the browser but modern server and browser already support compression so this makes only sense if the product data doesn't get good compression with it or you use a shared webhoster and/or your admin doesn't want to enable compression.